# Syntax of DISPLAY=:0 unity --replace or DISPLAY=:0 compiz --replace

Tags: command-line

Why don't the commands have a & between the setting of DISPLAY and running unity or compiz.

I understand that both work (re-starting unity or compiz), but fail to see why are they the way they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the value for `DISPLAY` is set for that one execution of one command, only.